# How to start docker from command line in mac

Tags: macos, docker

I have docker desktop installed in mac. So in order to start docker, I open applications and find docker. Then I can see a docker icon at the topbar. later I can run docker commands from the command line.

**My question is how do I start the docker itself from command line?**

Googling fetches me results on how to start a container from command line :|

Comment: `open /Applications/Docker.app`?

Comment: This should do. But I was looking for something like a `$ service docker-daemon start`

Comment: I'm not sure that there is any such service for Docker Desktop. nb Docker Desktop (both on Windows and Mac) is an app, not a service. Presumably intentional.

Comment: @Shobi the accepted answer does not actually answer the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On `macOS` you'd use `launchctl`:

It's unclear which service you are actually intending to run, although the equivalent to `service` or `systemctl` on `Linux` is `launchctl` on `macOS` (eg. running docker registry with `launchd`):

**Copy the Docker registry plist into place:**

```
plutil -lint registry/recipes/osx/com.docker.registry.plist
cp registry/recipes/osx/com.docker.registry.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
chmod 644 ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.docker.registry.plist
```

**Start the Docker registry:**

```
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.docker.registry.plist
```

**Restart the docker registry service**

```
launchctl stop com.docker.registry
launchctl start com.docker.registry
```

**Unload the docker registry service**

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.docker.registry.plist
```

↳ [Run the Docker Registry under launchd](https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/osx-setup-guide/)

Comment: Where did you find `com.docker.registry.plist`?

Comment: This documentation comes from 'Docker registry', which is talking about a *docker image* server (https://docs.docker.com/registry/). Isn't the question about starting the docker daemon from the command line?

Comment: Downvoting as this seem to answer a different question about starting a docker registry

Comment: Max, or the question is not really precise.

Answer (score 146):

You can open Docker Desktop on Mac using:-

```
open -a Docker
```

The Mac equivalent to `systemctl` or `service` is launchctl. **But** Docker Desktop is, presumably deliberately, packaged both on Mac and Windows as an application, not a service.

For shutdown, this:-

```
pkill -SIGHUP -f /Applications/Docker.app 'docker serve'
```

seems to work about as well as Quitting Docker from the GUI. By which I mean (a) when you restart Docker again it starts up with no complaints and (b) however I quit Docker Desktop, I still have a docker networking daemon left running.

Comment: open -a Docker works well ; but "systemctl: command not found" and there is no "launchctl restart" command

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll did you find a solution to this ?

Comment: The best I've got for Docker Desktop is `pkill -SIGHUP -f /Applications/Docker.app 'docker serve'` which appears to do a clean shutdown, as in when I then restart with open -a Docker, it starts up with no complaints and docker commands work as normal

Comment: I don't get it. I run `open -a Docker` and it immediately exits 0. Then I run `docker` and it says "docker: command not found". I'm connected to a headless server over ssh. How do I use docker without the `docker` command?

Comment: See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/444913/how-to-launch-docker-container-from-cli-in-macos-eg-docker-run

Comment: It worked well in my case. thanks

Comment: the open -a opens the docker, but in background. is there a cmd to open the Docker dashboard gui?

Answer (score 1):

On my Mac I started Docker Desktop via the Launchpad, and looked at the processes running with;

```
ps -ef | grep -i docker
```

I could see the app location to be;

```
/Applications/Docker 2.app
```

So I amended the above start up command slightly to;

```
open /Applications/Docker\ 2.app
```

And to kill all processes I first ran the following to see what the process name was;

```
pgrep -l Docker
38723 Docker Desktop
38731 Docker Desktop
38732 Docker Desktop
38735 Docker Desktop
38782 Docker Desktop
```

The passed this to killall;

```
killall 'Docker Desktop'
```

Answer (score 0):

start the docker desktop itself in macos :

> open -a Docker

stop the docker desktop itself in macos :

> killall Docker

Answer (score 0):

in MacOs - easiest way is to install docker desktop and then starting this will solve the "is daemon running?" problem...

Comment: Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem. Also your posts phrasing is distracting, indeed I am not even sure that you really try to answer. You might even be requesting help with your different or similar problem. In that case please delete this post. Consider taking the [tour].