# Is there a way to enable kubernetes on docker via command line on linux?

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes

I am using docker and trying to enable kubernetes and set CPU and Memory via command line.

I have looked at this answer but unfortunately cannot find this file.

[Is there any way to enable Kubernetes on Docker for Mac via terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54740934/is-there-any-way-to-enable-kubernetes-on-docker-for-mac-via-terminal)

Comment: Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/54820350/8645590, I see settings for kubernetes, CPU and memory for docker on Mac in `~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker/settings.json`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker does not have an app-ified version for Linux that I know of, so there is no relation to the Docker for Mac/Windows app. There are many tools to locally install Kubernetes on Linux so they probably didn't see much reason to make something new. Minikube is the traditional one, but you can also check out microk8s, k3s, KinD, and many others.